# Правильно ли говорить "По прилете"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Правильно говорить "по приезде", значит, по аналогии - "по прилете"?

Answer (score 8):

Да. Предлог ПО в значении после употребляется с предложным падежом: по возвращении, по окончании, по приезде, по прилете.

Comment: Прокомментируйте, пожалуйста, форму наречий *поутру* и *повечеру*. Они тоже имеют значение : "после наступления", но в них застыл Д.п. Также принято говорить *по восходу*, *по закату*. Вероятно, это устаревшие слова и сочетания? Но они красивые и выразительные.

Comment: Употребление предлога ПО с дательным падежом постепенно вытесняет употребление ПО с  предложным падежом. Т.е. более поздними вариантами являются как раз формы на -у.
  
Я не уверена, что поутру - тот же случай, что по приезде- по приезду. Все-таки значение поутру - утром или даже рано утром (как у Ушакова), а не после.

Comment: Поутру - как наступит утро, так же - повечеру, по восходу солнца, по закату (Мы пришли уже по закату). ///На сайтах аэропортов пишут : "Контроль по вылету и прилету". Здесь даже непонятно, какой смысл заключен в этом заголовке.

Comment: >тот же случай, что по приезде- по приезду.  
   
Это действительно другой случай. Из ряда по зиме, по жаре, по()темну и проч. Касательнол вытеснения форм предложного формами дательного - не уверен, что все так просто. Я что-то не слышал форм типа "по прибытию", но часто сталкивался, например, с путаницей "по предъявлении паспорта" или "по предъявлению". Вроде как первое должно означать временнУю последовательность, второе -  причинно-следственную. Во всяком случае так воспринимается многими вполне грамотными людьми. Модет в этом и зарыта собака?

Answer (score 2):

Вы путаете две разные вещи: склонение существительного по падежам и словообразование наречий. В первом случае употребляется предлог "по" (в значении после) + сущесвительное в предложном падеже. Во втором случае одно слово (наречие), которое пишется слитно - поутру, повечеру, потемну, подолгу. Образуется с префиксом по- и суффиксом -у. Аналогичным образом: понапрасну, попросту, попусту, поровну, почасту, подобру-поздорову. Ударение на префиксе или на корне. Обратите внимание, что все они либо устаревшие, либо являются просторечиями. Вот и получается, что некоторые люди в разговорной речи путают и используют для существительных вместо окончания -е суффикс -у от наречий.

Еще одним путающим фактом является то, что в случаях, когда предлог "по" выступает в других значенииях (пространственном, например), после него употребляется существительное в дательном падеже с окончанием на -у: по мосту, по носу, по рту, по порту и проч.

Резюме: определить, в какой значении выступает предлог "по". Если в значении "после", то употребляется предложный падеж.

Answer (score 1):

1. Одним делением НА СУЩЕСТВИТЕЛЬНЫЕ И НАРЕЧИЯ в решении этого вопроса не обойтись. Действительно, наречия могут мотивироваться существительными, и тогда их окончание переходит в суффикс – но этот суффикс-окончание тоже НАДО ОБЪЯСНИТЬ. Например: начало → поначалу, утро → поутрУ. Поутру – это утром, здесь предлог ПО имеет значение «в такую-то пору», а У – окончание Д.п. Мы говорим: приехать по весне (весной), цыплят считаем по осени (осенью).
2. Выражения вида долго →подолгу, напрасно → понапрасну тоже имеют суффикс У ОБОСНОВАННО. Сравнить: давно → издавна, суффикс А. Здесь фактически используется окончание кратких прилагательных, которые раньше склонялись как сущ. ср.рода: красна девица – красну девицу (также: правый → справа, направо). Таким образом, во всех эти словах мы также видим бывший Д.п.
3. Поэтому для решения задачи надо ЧЕТКО РАЗГРАНИЧИТЬ области употребления Д. и П. падежей.

3.1. Основным значением Д.п. является НАПРАВЛЕННОСТЬ: предмет выступает в качестве адресата или ориентира действия. В Грамматике-80  говорится, что Д.п. может обслуживать тему временной направленности: А) вернуться к обеду (приуроченность к сроку); Б) вернуться по весне  (указание на промежуток времени); в) не писать по году, работать по ночам – распределительное значение.

3.2. Предложный падеж (его местно-временная разновидность) – это падеж НЕНАПРАВЛЕННЫЙ, он указывает координаты действия: родиться в мае, встретиться на будущей неделе, присутствовать при разговоре. И главное для нас тема – обозначение следования во времени, значение «ПОСЛЕ», для чего используется предлог ПО, который обычно обслуживает Д.п.: «По смутном сне безделица тревожит» (Грибоедов).

1. Дерзкий grantum: "КОНТРОЛЬ ПО ВЫЛЕТУ И ПРИЛЕТУ". Здесь даже непонятно, какой смысл заключен в этом заголовке.

4.1. В перечень предоставляемых услуг по вылету и прилету входят… Здесь обычный Д.п., определяющий вид услуг.

4.2. Визы выдают по прилете. По прилете в паспорт надо поставить штамп. По вылете снаряда стопор под действием взводящей пружины поднимается вверх…  Это П.п. со значением «после».

4.3. В то же время такая тонкость в различении значений очень сложна для современного общества. Поэтому форма «по прилету  и вылету», как наиболее привычная, начинает применяться во всех случаях.